# swagger definition section date-time

Tags: swagger

I have the following in my definition section of a yaml.  When I put an invalid date it does not error as I would expect - treats it as being valid.  If I do not include the modified-time field I get the error that it is required - as I expect.  I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  The

```
  new-audit-data:
    type: object
    required:
      - modified_time
      - change
    properties:
      modified_time:
        type: string
        format: date-time
        example: 2018-01-21T23:28:56.782Z
      change: {}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"when I put an invalid date"*? What is *"it"*?

Comment: When I put the following {
    "modified_time": "",
    "change": {
  "address": "127 wishfull road, WY 12345"
 }
} I expect to get returned an error but instead it treats it as valid.  I don't get an error if I put anything other than a valid date format - so when I put "bad time" I still did not get an error.

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: "it does not error" - where the error is supposed to come from? Your API server, Swagger UI, something else? If you mean your API server, what is the code that handles the dates?

Comment: I don't have any special validation logic.  I thought the validation was a result of the "framework" in a manner similar to how it tells me when required fields are missing.

Comment: What framework do you use? It might not support validation out of the box. It's hard to suggest anything without seeing some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with this and realized my question probably makes no sense.  I have found a way to implement validation that is working.  Thank you to those who read my question.